# How to update multiple table using INNER JOIN and multiple SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update 2 tables using inner Join and setting values with 2 results from variables. I've finally succeeded to have it work for a SELECT.
I want to updates my tables having a long where clause. And set the result from a select query.

Code is fine with select I get my results :

```
SET @DefID = "5289";

SELECT pt1.ID, pt1.post_title, pt1.post_content, mt2.meta_value
FROM wp_posts AS pt1

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1
ON ( pt1.ID = mt1.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2
ON ( pt1.ID = mt2.post_id )
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3
ON ( pt1.ID = mt3.post_id )

WHERE 
    pt1.ID != @DefID
AND
    pt1.post_title LIKE '%Banda Sea DIVING Cruise with Tidak%'
AND 
    mt1.meta_key = 'tourmaster-tour-date-avail'
AND 
    CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2019-01-23'
AND 
    mt2.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data'
AND 
    mt3.meta_key = 'tourmaster-tour-duration'
AND 
    mt3.meta_value = '10'
AND    
    pt1.post_type = 'tour'
AND 
    pt1.post_status = 'publish'

ORDER BY mt1.meta_value ASC
```

But not working with UPDATE

```
SET @DefID = "myID";
SET @post_content = ( SELECT wp_posts_bak.post_content FROM wp_posts_bak WHERE wp_posts_bak.ID = @DefID );
SET @meta_value = ( SELECT wp_postmeta_bak.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta_bak WHERE wp_postmeta_bak.post_id = @DefID AND wp_postmeta_bak.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data');

UPDATE wp_posts_bak AS pt1, wp_postmeta_bak AS mt0

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_bak AS mt1 ON pt1.ID = mt1.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_bak AS mt2 ON pt1.ID = mt2.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_bak AS mt3 ON pt1.ID = mt3.post_id

SET 
    pt1.post_content  = @post_content,
    mt0.meta_value = @meta_value

WHERE
    pt1.ID != @DefID
AND 
    pt1.post_title LIKE '%Banda Sea DIVING Cruise with Tidak%'
AND 
    mt1.meta_key = 'tourmaster-tour-date-avail'
AND 
    CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2019-01-23'
AND 
    mt2.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data'
AND 
    mt3.meta_key = 'tourmaster-tour-duration'
AND 
    mt3.meta_value = '10'
AND    
    pt1.post_type = 'tour'
AND 
    pt1.post_status = 'publish'
```

Got the following error : Unknown column 'pt1.ID' in 'on clause.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the reason of the problem. In the UPDATE I had to remove the 2 tables.

So the solution is :

```
SET @DefID = "5289";
SET @post_content = ( SELECT wp_posts_bak.post_content FROM wp_posts_bak WHERE wp_posts_bak.ID = @DefID );
SET @meta_value = ( SELECT wp_postmeta_bak.meta_value FROM wp_postmeta_bak WHERE wp_postmeta_bak.post_id = @DefID AND wp_postmeta_bak.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data');

UPDATE wp_posts_bak AS pt1

INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_bak AS mt1 ON pt1.ID = mt1.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_bak AS mt2 ON pt1.ID = mt2.post_id
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta_bak AS mt3 ON pt1.ID = mt3.post_id

SET 
    pt1.post_content  = @post_content,
    mt2.meta_value = @meta_value

WHERE
    pt1.ID != @DefID
AND 
    pt1.post_title LIKE '%Banda Sea DIVING Cruise with Tidak%'
AND 
    mt1.meta_key = 'tourmaster-tour-date-avail'
AND 
    CAST(mt1.meta_value AS DATE) >= '2019-01-23'
AND 
    mt2.meta_key = '_cornerstone_data'
AND 
    mt3.meta_key = 'tourmaster-tour-duration'
AND 
    mt3.meta_value = '10'
AND    
    pt1.post_type = 'tour'
AND 
    pt1.post_status = 'publish'
```